# SAS - put empty space on string

Tags: string, sas

I have a script to write a SAS program (txt) that looks like this:

```
    /********* Import excel spreadsheet with model sepcs *****************/
    proc import file = "&mydir\sample.xls" out = model dbms = xls replace;
    run;
/********* Create program model *****************/
    data model;         
    set model;          
        dlb = resolve(dlb); 
        dub = resolve(dub); 
    run;                
    data model;
    set model;
        where2 = tranwrd(where,"="," ");
        where2 = tranwrd(where2,"<"," ");
        where2 = tranwrd(where2,">"," ");
        nword = countw(where2);
        bounds = trim(dlb)!!" "!!trim(dub);
        bounds = tranwrd(bounds,"="," "); 
        bounds = tranwrd(bounds,"<"," ");
        bounds = tranwrd(bounds,">"," ");  
        nbounds = countw(bounds);                                 
    run;
proc sql noprint;
    select max(nword) into: max_word from model ;
    select max(nbounds) into: max_aux from model ;                                              
    select name into: list_var separated by " " from dictionary.columns where libname = "WORK" and memname = "IMP" ;
quit;
/******* Generate Model ********/
    %macro generate_model;                                                                                                                          
        data model;                                                                                                                                     
        set model;                                                                                                                                      
        attrib wherev length = $500.;                                                                                                                   
            do i = 1 to countw(where2);                                                                                                                     
                %do j = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list_var));                                                                                                  
                    if upcase(scan(where2,i)) = "%upcase(%scan(&list_var,&j))" and scan(where2,i) not in ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9") then do; 
                        if missing(wherev) then wherev = trim(scan(where2,i));                                                                              
                        else if index(wherev,trim(scan(where2,i))) = 0 then do;                                                                             
                            wherev = trim(wherev)!!" "!!trim(scan(where2,i));                                                                               
                        end;                                                                                                                                
                    end;                                                                                                                                    
                %end;                                                                                                                                       
            end;                                                                                                                                            
        drop i where2;                                                                                                                                  
        run;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        data model;                                                                                                                                     
        set model;                                                                                                                                      
        attrib aux length = $500.;                                                                                                                      
            do i = 1 to countw(bounds);                                                                                                                     
                %do j = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list_var));                                                                                                  
                    if upcase(scan(bounds,i)) = "%upcase(%scan(&list_var,&j))" and scan(bounds,i) not in ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9") then do; 
                        if missing(aux) then aux = trim(scan(bounds,i));                                                                                    
                        else if index(aux,trim(scan(bounds,i))) = 0 then do;                                                                                
                            aux = trim(aux)!!" "!!trim(scan(bounds,i));                                                                                     
                        end;                                                                                                                                
                    end;                                                                                                                                    
                %end;                                                                                                                                       
            end;                                                                                                                                            
        drop i bounds;                                                                                                                                  
        run;                                                                                                                                            
    %mend;                                                                                                                                          
    %generate_model;

data outem.bound;
set outem.model;
attrib txt length = $2000.;
    txt = "******************Macros for variable"!!trim(dep)!!"******;";
    output;
    txt = "%"!!"macro bound"!!trim(dep)!!";";
    output;
    if not missing(lb) then do;
        txt ="LB="!!trim(lb)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(ub) then do;
        txt ="UB="!!trim(ub)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dlb) and not missing(lb) then do;
        txt ="LB=MAX(LB,"!!trim(dlb)!!");";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dlb) and missing(lb) then do;
        txt ="LB="!!trim(dlb)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dub) and not missing(ub) then do;
        txt ="UB=MIN(UB,"!!trim(dub)!!");";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dub) and missing(ub) then do;
        txt ="UB="!!trim(dub)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    txt = "%"!!"mend;";
    output;run;

data outem.imp;
    set outem.bound;
    file "&mydir\3_generate_models\3_model.sas" lrecl = 2000;
    put txt;
run;
```

The program works fine, however i can't manage to put empty space before `UB` or `LB`.

The output looks like this:

```
%macro boundHC0340;
LB=           1;
UB=           9;
%mend;
```

But I would like to get this:

```
%macro boundHC0340;
    LB=           1;
    UB=           9;
%mend;
```

The code already has some attempts to put empty space before `UB` and `LB`, but so far I couldn't manage.

I can put other characters and strings in there. I just can't put empty space before `UB` and `LB` in order to produce indented code.

I've tried something like this:

```
txt ="      LB="!!trim(lb)!!";";
```

But the empty space before `LB` does nothing.

However if i write this:

```
   txt ="******LB="!!trim(lb)!!";";
```

I get the asterisks on my program.

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Thank you very much for your support.

Best regards

Ps: here's the hyperlink to sample xls file: [sample.xls](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AYrIPx-Po7f4CbAtXWCzqzjBcESJXS8D)

Comment: How are you viewing the output? If you print it to the log, the leading spaces will be removed. If you open up the dataset in a viewtable window, you should be able to see them.

Comment: Greetings, the output is a SAS program file. I'm sorry i forgot to paste the last piece of code in my question. Will do so in a minute.

Comment: Done. So you see, when i open the file generated "3_model.sas",  I get `LB`and `UB` without empty space before.

Comment: I think I have an answer for you - have a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have built the variable TXT with the value you want to see you just need to add a format to your final step.  To avoid writing a lot of useless trailing blanks use the `$VARYING` format.  You will need to calculate the length of your string to use that format.

```
data outem.imp;
    set outem.bound;
    file "&mydir\3_generate_models\3_model.sas" lrecl = 2000;
    length= lengthn(txt);
    put txt $varying2000. length;
run;
```

But it is probably easier to just skip all of the concatenation and just use the power of the PUT statement itself to write the program directly from your data.  Then you can use things like pointer controls (`@3`) or named value `lb=` and other features of the `PUT` statement to format your program file.

```
data _null_;
  set outem.model;
  file "&mydir\3_generate_models\3_model.sas" ;
  put 72*'*' ';'
    / '* Macros for variable ' dep ';'
    / 72*'*' ';'
    / '%macro bound' dep ';'
  ;
  if not missing(lb) then put @3 lb= ';' ;
  if not missing(ub) then put @3 ub= ';' ;
  if not missing(dlb) and not missing(lb) then put
    @3 'LB=MAX(LB,' dlb ');'
  ;
  if not missing(dlb) and missing(lb) then put
    @3 'LB=' dlb ';'
  ;
  if not missing(dub) and not missing(ub) then put
    @3 'UB=MIN(UB,' dub ');'
  ;
  if not missing(dub) and missing(ub) then put
    @3 'UB=' dub ';'
  ;
  put '%mend bound' dep ';';
run;
```

Although looking at the logic of those IF statement why not reduce them to:

```
put @3 'LB=MAX(' lb ',' dlb ');' ;
put @3 'UB=MIN(' ub ',' dub ');' ;
```

Comment: Note to asker: this answer assumes that leading blanks have already been added where appropriate in a previous step.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the result of SAS applying left alignment by default for the `$w.` format of your variable when you use your put statement. You can override this by applying a format in the put statement and specifying what alignment you want to use:

```
data _null_;
  file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\example.txt";
  a = "       text here";

  /*Approach 1 - default behaviour*/
  /*No leading spaces on this line in output file (default)*/
  put a;


  /*Approach 2 - $varying + right alignment*/
  /*We need to right align text while preserving the number of leading spaces, so use $varying. */
  /*If every line is the same length, we can use $w. instead*/
  /*Use -r to override the default format alignment*/
  varlen = length(a);
  put a $varying2000.-r varlen;

  /*Approach 3 - manually specify indentation*/
  /*Alternatively - ditch the leading spaces and tell SAS which column to start at*/
  put @4 a;
run;
```

Try changing the last part of your code so it looks a bit like this (fix paths and dataset names as appropriate):

```
data bound;
set model;
attrib txt length = $2000.;
    txt = "******************Macros for variable"!!trim(dep)!!"******;";
    output;
    txt = "%"!!"macro bound"!!trim(dep)!!";";
    output;
    if not missing(lb) then do;
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        txt ="    LB="!!trim(lb)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(ub) then do;
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        /* LEADING SPACES ADDED HERE */
        txt ="    UB="!!trim(ub)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dlb) and not missing(lb) then do;
        txt ="LB=MAX(LB,"!!trim(dlb)!!");";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dlb) and missing(lb) then do;
        txt ="LB="!!trim(dlb)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dub) and not missing(ub) then do;
        txt ="UB=MIN(UB,"!!trim(dub)!!");";
        output;
    end;
    if not missing(dub) and missing(ub) then do;
        txt ="UB="!!trim(dub)!!";";
        output;
    end;
    txt = "%"!!"mend;";
    output;
run;

data _null_;
    set bound;
    file "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\example.sas" lrecl = 2000;
    varlen = length(txt);
    put txt $varying2000.-r varlen;
run;

x "notepad ""%sysfunc(pathname(work))\example.sas""";
```

Contents of example.sas (based on sample xls):

```
******************Macros for variableHC0340******;
%macro boundHC0340;
    LB=           1;
    UB=           9;
%mend;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue here is that i have a single variable named `txt`, so whatever i do affect the whole generated code.

Comment: The approach using `$varying` should work - have you tried it? If so, please post what output you got.

Comment: Also, please update your question so that you have a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: I've found a newbie way to deal with this. i just added `____` before `UB` and `LB`. Then when i open the text generated file i replace `____` with 4 empty spaces. Not the best way i'm sure but solves the problem.

Comment: I have updated my last data statement:                                                             
`data outem.imp;
 set outem.bound;
 file "&mydir\3_generate_models\3_model.sas" lrecl = 2000;
 varlen = length(txt);
   put varlen=;
   put txt $varying2000.-r varlen;
run;` However, this didn't work out. the output looks like this:                 
 `%macro boundHC0340;
varlen=16
LB=           1;
varlen=16
UB=           9;
varlen=6
%mend;`   So i guess i'll stick with the newbie way to work around the problem, however i thank you for your reply.

Comment: Please could you provide some sample input data that I can use to reproduce your results?

Comment: Also, please don't post big chunks of code in comments. Edit your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I only left the `put varlen=;` in there for illustrative purposes. You don't need to include it. I've removed it from my answer.

Comment: I've tried without that but still couldn't do it. I've provided full code with sample xls file in hyperlink. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample data and code. However, it is not particularly *minimal* - most of it does not relate to the problem at hand. Please read through the link I provided and see if you can produce a really minimal example.

Comment: Also, your sample code refers to macro variables whose values are not defined - `dlb` and `dub` (and a dataset, `work.imp`...), so it is not *complete*. When providing sample code and data please make sure it is completely self-contained. Also, please post sample data as plain text.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, you haven't actually included any logic that will put leading spaces in front of `txt`, so even after applying the alignment I suggested, there would be no difference.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an example of how you can implement it, and confirmed that the resulting output matches what you're trying to do.